# Eclipse shutdown when creating unsigned android apk

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, shutdown, unsigned

I'm freaking out with eclipse, I can generate a unsigned apk. When I start generating it, looks like everything goes good, but at the last moment when should finished generating the unsinged apk eclipse shutdown suddenly.

The weird thing is that in some moments after try it few times it generate it correctly, but I can't be like this, trying and trying every time.

Anyone have an idea what is going on here?

Comment: Just try reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue sometimes when generating **signed** APKs. This works for me: uncheck "Build automatically" (under the Project menu for me, I'm on iOS), clean the project, make a build.

Comment: I did it but then sth was wrong on one of the external libs... so I check it again and I solve it adding to Project Properties / Project reference the projects of the other libs. Looks like now is working